# RPC to Umbrel returns 403

Tags: python, umbrel

I have mangad to get closer to my goal.

My Code

```
# rpc_user and rpc_password are set in the bitcoin.conf file
rpc_user = "umbrel"
rpc_pass = "pass"
rpc_host = "192.168.1.122"
rpc_port = "8332"
rpc_connection = f"http://{rpc_user}:{rpc_pass}@{rpc_host}:{rpc_port}"
rpc_client = AuthServiceProxy(rpc_connection, timeout=240)
num_blocks = rpc_client.getblockcount()
print(num_blocks)
```

Which should just print out the BlockHeight of the node. But I get a 403 - Forbidden

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/donbolli/code/python/bitcoin/crawler/test.py", line 37, in <module>
    num_blocks = rpc_client.getblockcount()
  File "/media/donbolli/code/python/bitcoin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py", line 139, in __call__
    response = self._get_response()
  File "/media/donbolli/code/python/bitcoin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py", line 186, in _get_response
    raise JSONRPCException({
bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -342: non-JSON HTTP response with '403 Forbidden' from server
```

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden means that your authentication is incorrect. Either your username or your password is incorrect, or both.

Comment: I double checked with my node and copied user and password from umbrel. still i get a 403

Comment: If you changed the config to use a different user and password, you will need to restart the node for it to take effect.

Comment: My research brought up, umbrel doesn't allow that. So i download Bitcoin Core and synced it. Now i get Connection refused (Errorno 111), what is missing?